# How to create a stored procedure that return error message and print that error message using message box from front end

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure :

```
alter procedure [usp_chkuseridpwd]
as
begin
    declare 
        /*variable declaration */
        @sql as varchar(max),
        @tblname varchar(max),
        @user_name varchar(max),
        @user_password varchar(max),
        @response varchar(max),
        @count int,
        @passwd as varchar(max),
        @temppasswd as varchar(max)

    set @sql = 'select COUNT(*) from user_master where USER_NAME like '+@user_name+' and pasword like '+@user_password+''

    exec(@sql)

    if(@count > 0)
    begin
        set @temppasswd=('select password from user_master where USER_NAME='+@user_name+'')

        if (@temppasswd = @passwd)
            set @response=('the password is incorrect !')

        print @response //here I want to return response using message box
    end
    else 
        set @response = ('The user Id is not available')

    print @response //here I want to return response using message box
end
```

And here I have following function that send some parameter like table name, user name, password (if stored procedure returns false, then it should be display "invalid user name", else "user is valid user")

```
public DataTable chkuseridpwd(ref string tname,ref string uname,ref string pwd)
{
    try
    {
        if (cnn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cnn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_chkuseridpwd", cnn);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblname", tname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", uname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", pwd);

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtTbl);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }

    return dtTbl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this **RAISERROR** function of SQL Server

```
RAISERROR('Here Your Error Message')
```

As per your code use  `RAISERROR(@response)`

You will catch it as exception message at front end

Comment: Raising error for returning a message like the op wants is not a good thing. Output variable will work in this case.

Comment: 1 more question sir, Should i change my method's datatype ?

Comment: If you can handle thing without raising the error, you should do that first. @Vivek You should read about the output parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use **output** parameters for this task. Here are some links for more reading.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748619/ADO-NET-How-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-output

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10261.stored-procedures-output-parameters-return-values

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx